# ¿Cómo puedo nombrar un archivo .json?

Tags: python

¿Cómo logro nombrar un archivo .json por medio de un imput?

Este es un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr

```py
x = input('Ingrese un nombre: ')
archivo = x.json
```

Comment: `archivo = f"{x}.json"`

Comment: Gracias Christian

Comment: de nada, lo que he utilizado se llama *f-strings* (format strings), pero tambien lo puedes hacer concatenando `archivo = x + ".json"` ^_^